# How did Lucius Malfoy get back to being a school governor?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I don't have access to my copy of Prisoner of Azkaban currently, but I'm pretty sure I remember correctly that Lucius Malfoy is one of he school governors, since he is a big part of Hagrid's appeal and Buckbeak's attempted execution.  But as I was rereading Chamber of Secrets, I noticed this:

> Lucius Malfoy had been sacked as a school governor.  Draco was no longer strutting around the school as if he owned the place.

Am I wrong?  Or is it someone else?

Comment: Point to where he appears again as a school governor. He was sacked, but he still had ties with the ministry.

Comment: The reason he is a big part of the trial for Bucbeack's beheading is that the child who was attacked by the Hippogriph was his son, if it was anyone else he would not have cared at all and just hoped it was a mudblood that was attacked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There's no indication that Lucius was reinstated as a Governor.**

When the governors write to Hagrid, the book reads:

> *We have decided to uphold the official complaint of Mr. Lucius Malfoy, and this matter will therefore be taken to the Committee for the Disposal of Dangerous Creatures.* [...]
>
> There followed a list of the school governors.

It seems a little unusual for the governors to be deciding on this issue if Malfoy was still among their members. (And Harry et al. know that Lucius was fired as governor; they'd be able to point out a conflict of interest/foul play if he'd been reinstated and was ruling on his own case.)

Hagrid makes strong implications that he can stiffarm the governors and/or Ministry, but doesn't mention anything about his reinstatement:

> “Them Disposal devils, they're all in Lucius Malfoy’s pocket! Scared o’ him!” [...]
>
> “That Commitee's in Lucius Malfoy’s pocket.”
>
> “Yeh know what Lucius Malfoy’s like... threatened ’em, I expect... an’ the executioner, Macnair, he’s an old pal o’ Malfoy’s”

but that simply stems from the fact that he was well-connected, and exerted considerable political influence. He doesn't need to be a governor to do that (although he took advantage of it when he was a governor).

I searched the text of *Prisoner of Azkaban* for all mentions of the word "Lucius" and "governor"; there's nothing which mentions his reinstatement.

Answer (score 9):

Lucius Malfoy was one of the governors of Hogwarts during the events of the Chamber of Secrets

> Mr. Lucius Malfoy, a governor of Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, where the enchanted car crashed earlier this year, called today for Mr. Weasley’s resignation. “Weasley has brought the Ministry into disrepute,” Mr. Malfoy told our reporter. “He is clearly unfit to draw up our laws and his ridiculous Muggle Protection Act should be scrapped immediately.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 12, The Polyjuice Potion*</sup></sub>

But he got fired.

> Hogwarts was back to normal with only a few, small differences — Defense Against the Dark Arts classes were canceled (“but we’ve had plenty of practice at that anyway,” Ron told a disgruntled Hermione) and Lucius Malfoy had been sacked as a school governor.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 18, Dobby’s Reward*</sup></sub>

Based on the books, Lucius Malfoy does not get the post back next year.

> “Keep talking, Malfoy, and I’ll give you a real injury,” snarled Ron.
>
> “– he’s complained to the school governors. And to the Ministry of Magic. Father’s got a lot of influence, you know. And a lasting injury like this” — he gave a huge, fake sigh — “who knows if my arm’ll ever be the same again?”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 7, The Boggart in the Wardrobe*</sup></sub>

Couple of years later, he was in Azkaban on valid charges.

> “The Dementors have left Azkaban,” said Malfoy quietly. “Dad and the others’ll be out in no time...”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 38, The Second War Begins*</sup></sub>

So it is unlikely that he ever got the post back. But there is no canonical evidence to support this claim.